# Is char possibly faster than unsigned char?

Tags: c

I'm wondering why it's implementation defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

If both types are sufficient for my application, should I prefer `char` over `unsigned char`  (and `signed char`) because it might be faster?

Or are the reasons purely historical?

Comment: Thanks for linking to a possible duplicate. I didn't find that one because I looked for "fast".